# Relacionamento com Admin do Django

Tags: python, django

Sou iniciante com Python e Django e estou fazendo um menu generico, gostaria de saber como listar no Admin do Django os itens relacionados a um menu no ModelAdmin do Menu

```
class Menu(models.Model):
        menu = models.CharField('Menu', max_length=150)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.menu

class Item(models.Model):
          label = models.CharField('Item', max_length=150)
          url = models.CharField('Url', max_length=150)
          menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi corretamente a sua pergunta, para disponibilizar um determinado model na página do admin, basta ir no seu admin.py e inscrever o seu model lá:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Menu, Item

admin.site.register(Menu)
admin.site.register(Item)
```

Manda um feedback se a solução é a correta.

Answer (score 0):

Cada aplicação Django ela tem um arquivo **admins.py** nele você consegue registrar seus modelos na página de administração do Django.

Caso queira listar os items, você faria:

```
from .models import Item

class ItensAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    #List_display são itens que irá mostrar na tabela.
    list_display = ('label', 'url', 'menu')

    '''
    List_filter é caso queira filtrar o item por alguma opção. Não é 
    necessário usar de acordo com o que você tem, mas mesmo assim é bom 
    saber caso precise em outro momento. No exemplo, filtrei por hidden, ou 
    seja, quando clickar na opção hidden que irá aparecer no painel, ele me 
    mostrará os itens que estão invisiveis.
    list_filter = ['hidden']
    Por último, você irá registrar seu model para que ele aparece lá.
    admin.site.register(Model, Classe que criamos no Django Admin)
    o seu ficará:
    admin.site.register(Item, ItensAdmin)
    '''
```